# Redirect bound port

Tags: windows-7, networking, port-forwarding

I want to use a lighting control software (M-PC) on Windows 7 that sends its command via Art-Net (UDP). I installed a loopback adapter for the software to send on and wrote a little script that should receive these commands and send them to my USB Interface.

But the control software also binds the port it is sending on. Because of that my script cant listen on this port. I also tried setting SO_REUSEADDR in the socket of the script but that didnt make any difference.

So I was wondering if there is some way to redirect this port to some other port where my script can listen even if it is already bound by the software.